# Ignore parent divs width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I have had issues with modify a navigation bar for mobile. I want the navigation bar to ignore its parent div **`inner-wrapper`** width of `80%` and use a full width of `100%`.

The most logical solution I can think of is to set **`header: relative`, `width: 100%`** and **`header li` to `absolute` with a `width` of `100%`**. However, this doesn't seem to work.

I want each navigation to have a full width of the screen rather than a full width of its parent wrapper.

```css
.header {
  background-color: #FFB6C1;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.header h2 {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.header h3 {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-family: 'Petit Formal Script';
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.header span {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.header ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10%
}

.header ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Podkova', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Navigation Menu click for mobile */

.mobile-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  /* Styles */
  /* Display flex to change the ordering of HTML elemtns*/
  .inner-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .header-title {
    order: 1;
  }
  .header-description {
    order: 2;
  }
  .dropdown {
    order: 3;
  }
  .header-li {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header ul {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  .mobile-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: initial;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .header ul li {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Header and Navigation -->
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <h2 class="header-title">text</h2>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="mobile-menu">
        <p align="right">Menu</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="header-li">
        <li>About me</li>
        <li>Progress</li>
        <li>Food</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h3 class="header-description">text</span></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried position: absolute; on the nav ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using viewport units seems initially like a good idea, though in this case it is not necessary and will be of no use as the `header` uses `overflow: hidden`.

*Note, if you start using `100vw` it can cause unwanted scrollbar and/or make the element behave in an unwanted way when its parent/body has scrollbar*

---

As the `header-li` relates to the `header` (closest ancestor having a position other than `static`), simply use `100%` and `transform: translate` to position it.

```
.header-li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  background: lime;
}
```

*Note, it below sample I colored it light gray so one see how it positions itself*

Stack snippet

```css
.header {
  background-color: #FFB6C1;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.header h2 {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.header h3 {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-family: 'Petit Formal Script';
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.header span {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.header ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10%
}

.header ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Podkova', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header-li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
}


/* Navigation Menu click for mobile */

.mobile-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}


/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  /* Styles */
  /* Display flex to change the ordering of HTML elemtns*/
  .inner-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .header-title {
    order: 1;
  }
  .header-description {
    order: 2;
  }
  .dropdown {
    order: 3;
  }
  .header-li {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header ul {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  .mobile-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: initial;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .header ul li {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Header and Navigation -->
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <h2 class="header-title">text</h2>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="mobile-menu">
        <p align="right">Menu</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="header-li">
        <li>About me</li>
        <li>Progress</li>
        <li>Food</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h3 class="header-description"><span>text</span></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want the `header-li` to expand beyond the `header` as well, you will need to both remove `overflow: hidden`, use `100vw` and remove the `padding` the `ul` has as a default (or else you'll get a scroll)

```css
.header {
  background-color: #FFB6C1;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.header h2 {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.header h3 {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-family: 'Petit Formal Script';
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.header span {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.header ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10%
}

.header ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Podkova', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header-li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Navigation Menu click for mobile */

.mobile-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}


/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  /* Styles */
  /* Display flex to change the ordering of HTML elemtns*/
  .inner-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .header-title {
    order: 1;
  }
  .header-description {
    order: 2;
  }
  .dropdown {
    order: 3;
  }
  .header-li {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header ul {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  .mobile-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: initial;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .header ul li {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Header and Navigation -->
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <h2 class="header-title">text</h2>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="mobile-menu">
        <p align="right">Menu</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="header-li">
        <li>About me</li>
        <li>Progress</li>
        <li>Food</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h3 class="header-description"><span>text</span></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the navigation to have full width of the screen use `width: 100vw;` on the child. That means 100% of the view width

Comment: This somewhat worked, it uses 90%,  it forces itself over margin-right however stays clear of the 10% margin-left. Not sure why it's not completely covering the view width?

Comment: it has to do with the wrapper being set to margin:0 auto. The centering is taking affect - for some reason ignoring one margin but not the other.

Comment: you can give it `margin: -10%` or just remove the margin that is affecting it

Answer (score 1):

How's this James?

```css
.theContainer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.theParent {
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.theChild {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="theContainer">
  <div class="theParent">
    This is the parent trying to restrict the child to 80% width.
    <div class="theChild">
      This is the child with 100% width ignoring parent.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe this is the solution I've tried already, if you read my post :)